# Web Testing Software

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, web-testing

I am working as a web developer in a company. I am not aware of anything related to testing. Our company is planning to buy some testing softwares. Presently we are working on ASP.NET. We will be working on PHP and JAVA in future. I need your help to find out the best but cost effective testing sofwares. I have got some suggestions on TFS and Visual Studio Testing tool. Don't know what to do. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 4):

I use this framework for web tests http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Selenium is perhaps the most commonly known and used framework. You can drive it in a number of ways and build it into automated suites of tests. It's a good place to start. There are other products around as well. Some free and others, well, how deep are you pockets ? :-)

Comment: Thanks for you prompt answer. I'll check Selenium. I really don't have any idea about the pocket size :( It's a company descision. But anything good will be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There are list open source Testing tools are available 
for **Functional Testing**

1. Selenium IDE and selenium web driver PHPUnit is a unit testing
2. framework for the PHP programming language JUnit is a unit testing
3. framework for the Java programming language
4. Jasmine is an open source testing framework for JavaScript
5. Watir stands for "Web Application Testing in Ruby." It works with
   applications written in any language, not only Ruby

For **Performance Testing**

1. Apache JMeter
2. Gatling
3. LoadUI is an open source and free load testing software

For web application testing you go with selenium web driver it is mostly used for functional testing
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Selenium and WatiN are both great options. I would recommend [Fluent Automation](http://fluent.stirno.com) which is a DSL that lives on top of either Selenium, WatiN or PhantomJS for test execution.

I'm the developer of Fluent Automation, but it really does work well. Its available as a NuGet package and can automate IE, Firefox and Chrome depending on which provider you choose.

Answer (score 0):

For web application testing chek out [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) and [Watir](http://watir.com/). TFS has a lot of functions not related to testing, it's more CI platform. If you need CI platform consider [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) and [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on which level you want to test, if you want to do UT, Xunit like framework maybe a good choice, but if you change language test cases are almost useless. If you want to test the webside base on functional, you can choose UIbased testing framework like selenium or watir whatever. The good news is test cases is not rely on backend language, but it is strong rely on UI elements. To fix that, you can choose interface(post/get) testing.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP and .Net use `selenium IDE` for regression testing and for load testing using Jmeter both this tool is free and open source or if you want to buy some tool for automation then use QTP and Load runner.

Now a days Selenium is most popular and its is very to under for selenium ide you do not need have to know about any programming language but in selenium if you use webdriver then you ahve to know about some programming language

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on Web Applications, Performance would play a major part. I believe you should also go for buying Performance Testing Tool (Load Runner).
There is an open source tool for Performance Testing (Jmeter).